# multiple tableView reloadData()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a dynamic tableview inside of a Static tableview, but I can't get reloadData to call the cellForRowAtIndexPath when calling it on my second tableview. Is there a way I need to populate the Cell data in the second tableview? Or is there a better way to do this? I have attached a visual to see if that helps.[image]

Here is the code i have now:

```
import UIKit
import CalendarView
import SwiftMoment

class TimeAwayRequestTableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet var calendarView: CalendarView!
@IBOutlet weak var selectedTableView: UITableView!

var selectedDates : [Moment] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    calendarView.delegate = self

    selectedTableView.delegate = self
    selectedTableView.dataSource = self
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var returnInt = 0
    if tableView == selectedTableView {
        returnInt = 10
    } else {
        if section == 0 {
            returnInt = 2
        }
        if section == 1 {
            returnInt = 1
        }
    }


    return returnInt
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    var numberOfSections = 0
    if tableView == selectedTableView {
        numberOfSections = 0
    } else {
        numberOfSections = 2
    }

    return numberOfSections
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()

    if tableView == selectedTableView {
        cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("dateCell")!
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .NoStyle

        let date = selectedDates[indexPath.row].date

        cell.textLabel?.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)

    } else {
        cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    }

  return cell
}



}

extension TimeAwayRequestTableViewController : CalendarViewDelegate {

func calendarDidSelectDate(date: Moment) {
    selectedDates.append(date)
    print(selectedDates)

    selectedTableView.frame.size.height = CGFloat(selectedDates.count) * CGFloat(44)

    self.tableView.contentSize.height = self.tableView.frame.size.height + self.selectedTableView.frame.size.height

}

func calendarDidPageToDate(date: Moment) {
    print(date)
}

}
```

Comment: Try returning 1 instead of 0 from numbeOfSectionsInTableView.

Answer (score -1):

Try this [StaticDataTableViewController](https://github.com/peterpaulis/StaticDataTableViewController.)

It enables animated hide/show of static cells.So may be helpful to you.